# Object Oriented Programming Nth Child

Tags: c#, object, oop

language specific (however, if you need a language please use C++/C# or Javascript). I trying to figure out how I would go about doing this, and how I would access the child objects from a parent object.

Say I have the following classes, and these are not written properly etc... :

Class: `roomContainer` (container of objects)
Class: `Table` (base class for a table, contains property of maximum-seats, current-number-of-seats, array of seats )
Class: `Desk` (extends Table, contains property for maximum draws, array of draws )
Class: `seat` (base class for seats, contains property of maximum-legs, arm-rest, back-rest)
Class: `couch` (extends seat, adds property maximum seats)

If I create an instance of `roomContainer`, and add within it's container a table, couch. Within the table I create multiple seats (or chairs), and a desk.

How would I be able to access the property of child objects property, when the parent has a container of different objects. I.e the `roomContainer` Container of objects, one of them is a table, and a desk - where the desk has different properties and an array of draws etc..  ?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something called the [Composite Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).  This allows you to nest objects (as you described), and hold references to both the parent and the children (though some implementations do no maintain a parent reference - this is optional).

Here is an example implementation using your schema:

```
public static class Program     // the supporting class definitions are below
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // create a root container
        var room = new RoomContainer();

        // create a child
        var table = new Table(room, 4);

        // put the table in the room
        room.Add(table);

        MakeMess(room);
    }

    //  to show you how to access the properties 
    //  if you don't already have a reference:
    public static void MakeMess(RoomContainer room)
    {
        if(room == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("room");
        }
        var seats = room.GetChildren<Table>().First().Seats.ToArray();
        for (int index = 0; index < seats.Length; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have kicked over Seat #{0}",(index+1).ToString());
        }
    }

}

//  This is the base class of the components and provides the core functionality.
//  You will want to make this object's interface minimal, so that the logic 
//  is consistent with all its children (without knowing what they might be in advance)

public abstract class Component
{

    private readonly IList<Component> _children;
    private readonly Component _container;

    protected Component(Component container)
    {
        _container = container;
        _children = new Component[] { };
    }

    public bool IsRoot { get { return _container == null; } }

    public abstract bool IsContainer { get; }


    public virtual void Add(Component component)
    {
        if (component == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("component");
        }
        if (!IsContainer)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Add is not supported by leaf components");
        }
        _children.Add(component);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetChildren<T>()
        where T: Component
    {
        if (!IsContainer)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Only containers have children");
        }
        return _children.OfType<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Component> Children
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsContainer)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Only containers have children");
            } 
            return _children;
        }
    }

}

public class RoomContainer : Component
{
    public RoomContainer() : base(null)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsContainer { get { return true; } }
}

public class Table : Component
{
    private readonly int _maximumSeatCount;

    public Table(Component container, int maximumSeatCount) : base(container)
    {
        _maximumSeatCount = maximumSeatCount;
    }

    public override bool IsContainer { get { return true; } }


    protected virtual bool CanAdd(Component component)
    {
        return component is Seat && MaximumSeatCount > CurrentSeatCount;
    }

    public override void Add(Component component){
            if(CanAdd(component)){
                 base.Add(component);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The component was an invalid child of Table and could not be added.");
            }
       }

    public int MaximumSeatCount { get { return _maximumSeatCount; } }
    public int CurrentSeatCount { get { return Seats.Count(); } }
    public IEnumerable<Seat> Seats { get { return Children.OfType<Seat>(); } }
} 
public class Seat : Component
{
    // you can restrict the constructor to only accept a valid parent
    public Seat(Table table) : base(table)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsContainer
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the all share common methods, for example `Render(), Update(), SaveDetails(int Id), LoadDetails(int Id)` then you could make them all inherit from a base class, or all impliment a common interface. This would remove the need for casting (below) when calling a common method (or accessing a common property).
To access properties unique to the derived class you would check the type of the child object, then cast the child object to access the property.

EDIT: Example:

```
foreach(Object obj in Room.ChildObjects)
{
    if(obj is Desk)
    {
        Desk DeskObj = obj as Desk; // Cast the object reference as a desk.
        DeskObj.MaxDraws = 50; // It's a big desk!
        DestObj.Draws[1] = new Draw(); // ......
    }
}
```

Comment: If they are different types of objects, and don't always share the methods (of if they do have the same methods take different types of inputs), would I need to retrieve the object and operate on the object from the container. For example, if i need to set the properties of the draws would I need to go to RoomContainer > Desk Object > Draws, have a method that find the appropriate draw object from the array and return the object. Then once I have the object returned invoke it's property/methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Desk> desks = roomContainer.OfType<Desk>();
//Iterate and do stuff.
IEnumerable<Table> tables = roomContainer.OfType<Table>();
//Iterate and do stuff.
```

Comment: This only makes sense if `RoomContainer` implements IEnumerable